# How to convert Sentinel-3 .nc-file into .tiff-file?

Tags: r, raster, tiff, netcat, ncdf4

regarding the conversion of .nc-files into .tiff-files i encounter the problem of loosing geoinformation of my pixels. I know that other users experienced the same problem and tried to solve it via kotlin but failed. i would prefer a solution using R. see here for kotlin approach URL:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259700/converting-sentinel-3-data-netcdf-to-geotiff

I downloaded freely available Sentinel-3 data of the ESA (URL:https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home). This data comes unfortunately in the .nc-format, so I want to convert it into the .tiff-format. I have already tried various approaches, but failed. What I have tried so far:

```
data_source <- 'D:/user_1/01_test_data/S3A_SL_1_RBT____20180708T093240_20180708T093540_20180709T141944_0179_033_150_2880_LN2_O_NT_003.SEN3/F1_BT_in.nc'
# define path to .nc-file

data_output <- 'D:/user_1/01_test_data/S3A_SL_1_RBT____20180708T093240_20180708T093540_20180709T141944_0179_033_150_2880_LN2_O_NT_003.SEN3/test.tif'
# define path of output .tiff-file


###################################################
# 1.) use gdal_translate via Windows cmd-line in R
# see here URL:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046282/convert-netcdf-nc-to-geotiff

system(command = paste('gdal_translate -of GTiff -sds -a_srs epsg:4326', data_source, data_output))
# hand over character string to Windows cmd-line to use gdal_translate


###################################################
# 2.) use the raster-package
# see here URL:https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_convert_a_NetCDF4_file_to_GeoTIFF_using_R2

epsg4326 <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
# proj4-code
# URL:https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/proj4/

specific_band <- raster(data_source)
crs(specific_band) <- epsg4326
writeRaster(specific_band, filename = data_output)


# both approaches work, i can convert the files from .nc-format into .tiff-format, but i **loose the geoinformation for the pixels** and just get pixel coordinates instead of longlat-values.
```

I really appreciate any solutions that keep the geoinformation for the pixels!

Thanks a lot in advance, ExploreR

Comment: can you provide a link to an example file?

Comment: yes, for sure, just take this url for a dataset as an example URL:https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('03efce00-58ca-4c54-ba98-ae49e8b7d256')/$value

Comment: that requires a user name and password

Comment: Yes, that is correct, i am sorry for that. But you could sign up for the Copernicus hub of the European Space Agency (ESA). It is for free and you have access to many more interesting datasets than the one i am pointing to... there is even an R package (getSpatialData) provided by J. Schwalb-Willmann, mentioned by Nature in a toolbox article, where you can download Copernicus data in a very convenient way. URL:https://github.com/16EAGLE/getSpatialData

Answer (score 1):

As @j08lue [points out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/272970/8993),

> The product format for Sentinel 3 products is horrible. Yes, the data
>   values are stored in netCDF, but the coordinate axes are in separate
>   files and it is all just a bunch of files and metadata.

I did not find any documentation (I assume it must exist), but it seems you can get the data like this:

```
library(ncdf4)
# coordinates
nc <- nc_open("geodetic_in.nc")
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "longitude_in")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "latitude_in")
# including elevation for sanity check only
elv <- ncvar_get(nc, "elevation_in")
nc_close(nc)

# the values of interest
nc <- nc_open("F1_BT_in.nc")
F1_BT <- ncvar_get(nc, "F1_BT_in")
nc_close(nc)

# combine 
d <- cbind(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(elv), as.vector(F1_BT_in))
```

Plot a sample of the locations. Note that the raster is rotated

```
plot(d[sample(nrow(d), 25000),1:2], cex=.1)
```

I would need to investigate a bit more to see how to write a rotated raster.

For now, a *not recommended* shortcut could be to rasterize to a non-rotated raster

```
e <- extent(as.vector(apply(d[,1:2],2, range))) + 1/120
r <- raster(ext=e, res=1/30)
#elev <- rasterize(d[,1:2], r, d[,3], mean)
F1_BT <- rasterize(d[,1:2], r, d[,4], mean, filename="")
plot(F1_BT)
```

Answer (score 0):

so that´s what i have done so far - unfortunately the raster is not somehow rotated by 180degree, but somehow distorted in another way...

```
# (1.) first part of the code adapted to Robert Hijmans approach (see code of answer provided above)

nc_geodetic <- nc_open(paste0(wd, "/01_test_data/sentinel_3/geodetic_in.nc"))
nc_geodetic_lon <- ncvar_get(nc_geodetic, "longitude_in")
nc_geodetic_lat <- ncvar_get(nc_geodetic, "latitude_in")
nc_geodetic_elv <- ncvar_get(nc_geodetic, "elevation_in")
nc_close(nc_geodetic)
# to get the longitude, latitude and elevation information

F1_BT_in_vars <- nc_open(paste0(wd, "/01_test_data/sentinel_3/F1_BT_in.nc"))
F1_BT_in <- ncvar_get(F1_BT_in_vars, "F1_BT_in")
nc_close(F1_BT_in_vars)
# extract the band information



###############################################################################
# (2.) following part of the code is adapted to @Matthew Lundberg rotation-code see URL:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496210/rotate-a-matrix-in-r

rotate_fkt <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))
# create rotation-function

F1_BT_in_rot180 <- rotate_fkt(rotate_fkt(F1_BT_in))
# rotate raster by 180degree 

test_F1_BT_in <- raster(F1_BT_in_rot180)
# convert matrix to raster



###############################################################################
# (3.) extract corner coordinates and transform with gdal

writeRaster(test_F1_BT_in, filename = paste0(wd, "/01_test_data/sentinel_3/test_flip.tif"), overwrite = TRUE)
# write the raster layer

data_source_flip <- '"D:/unknown_user/X_processing/01_test_data/sentinel_3/test_flip.tif"'
data_tmp_flip <- '"D:/unknown_user/X_processing/01_test_data/temp/test_flip.tif"'
data_out_flip <- '"D:/unknown_user/X_processing/01_test_data/sentinel_3/test_flip_ref.tif"'
# define input, temporary output and output for gdal-transformation

nrow_nc_mtx <- nrow(nc_geodetic_lon)
ncol_nc_mtx <- ncol(nc_geodetic_lon)
# investigate on matrix size of the image

xy_coord_char1 <- as.character(paste("1", "1", nc_geodetic_lon[1, 1], nc_geodetic_lat[1, 1]))
xy_coord_char2 <- as.character(paste(nrow_nc_mtx, "1", nc_geodetic_lon[nrow_nc_mtx, 1], nc_geodetic_lat[nrow_nc_mtx, 1]))
xy_coord_char3 <- as.character(paste(nrow_nc_mtx, ncol_nc_mtx, nc_geodetic_lon[nrow_nc_mtx, ncol_nc_mtx], nc_geodetic_lat[nrow_nc_mtx, ncol_nc_mtx]))
xy_coord_char4 <- as.character(paste("1", ncol_nc_mtx, nc_geodetic_lon[1, ncol_nc_mtx], nc_geodetic_lat[1, ncol_nc_mtx]))
# extract the corner coordinates from the image

system(command = paste('gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp ', xy_coord_char1, ' -gcp ', xy_coord_char2, ' -gcp ', xy_coord_char3, ' -gcp ', xy_coord_char4, data_source_flip, data_tmp_flip))
system(command = paste('gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=NONE ', data_tmp_flip,  data_out_flip))
# run gdal-transformation
```